# Looking for paypal payments tutorial

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am looking for a tutorial which will show me how to accept paypal payments as I am not having much luck with the documentation.

In the tutorial, I just need to understand how to capture a unique identifier when the payment has been initiated, and then use the unique identifier to update the database record when payment confirms the payment via ipn.

Does such a tutorial exist?

Basically, I already have the payments working i.e. a user can make a payment and payment can send a notification to the ipn script, but I can't tell which payment paypal has accepted.

Comment: This tutorial explains integrating paypal on android http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-integrating-paypal-using-php-mysql-part-1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There guide is pretty well written and covers all of this:

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/en_US/files/developer/PP_OrderMgmt_IntegrationGuide.pdf

Comment: Looking at this guide, would I be right to assume that I need to continue reading about IPN instead of PDT?  Basically, I will just be taking a 1 off subscription fee from the users and will not be selling anything.  Does that mean I don't need PDT as I am not a merchant?

Comment: yes, but it only guide and not complete how to do that. I think we as programmer better get tutorial by code. not just explanation.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal has multiple ways to accept payment. Here is the site to PayPal developer site where you will find all the options: https://www.x.com/community/ppx/dev-tools

Comment: I've posted 2 comments at x.com, 6 days later, 0 replies.  so that forum is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial on [how to integrate your shopping cart with PayPal Website Payments Standard](http://www.softarea51.com/blog/how-to-integrate-your-custom-shopping-cart-with-paypal-website-payments-standard-using-php/).

The PayPalIPN class provided by the toolkit I developed handles the entire IPN confirmation under the hood. You only need to get the data and update the order in the database. Optionally, you can also notify the customer with your own customized invoice or other information.